# Anchor settings in my own control vs. resizing behaviour on the parent form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, forms

I've build my own control in Visual Studio 2010. I've arranged several Windows controls on the form with specific anchor settings. In the control's own designer, the resizing behaviour is ok, but when I resize the control as is in the main program, the anchor settings of the controls inside my own control are ignored.
Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: Can you show some screenshots illustrating this behavior?  What works and what doesn't work...

Comment: I see your problem but I'm not sure where the problem lies.  I think I'd need to play with an example project to be able to figure it out...

Comment: So.. unresolved until now. Any tipps?

Comment: Push back.  This is really the type of problem that you need an actual project to play with to figure out.  Sorry!....

Answer (score 0):

I assume that happens because your own `CustomControl` is not resizing. Try adding anchors to your `CustomControl` like:

```
var lc = new CustomControl();
lc.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;

this.Controls.Add(lc);
```

and see if it helped you.

Comment: I'm now sure if this is the right solution. But a little example: imagine your are editing your own control in it's own form. E.g. a textbox in a groupbox. When you resize the groupbox, with the textbox's anchors set it behaves right. But if you add the control to a new form, the textbox's behaviour is wrong. Why is the sense of adding anchors in the custom control if they don't have any effect in the resulting application?

Comment: Because your custom control is a container in it self (like a group box in your example) so it has to resize as well to controls inside of it move/resize as well. Your custom control has effect almost the same as `Panel`

Comment: Yes. I would have expected that too as your're saying. But if we stay at th example of a panel in my panel the inner controls wouldn't resize even if the anchors are set correctly.

Comment: Yes because `Panel` itself must be resized to anchors be able to work. Take a look here [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) especially this line: Use the Anchor property to define how a control is automatically resized as its parent control is resized.

Comment: Hmm. I think we are talking about different things. If you create your own control with a let us says picturebox inside. And you set the picturebox's bottom anchor to true. Now you use your control in another project. And you resize your control in the VS forms designer. E.g. you resize it in height. Does your picture box resize too? Mine does not. And it's bottom, anchor IS set to "true".

Comment: Because anchor set only to bottom will just stick your picture box to bottom border of user control, to make it resize vertically it has to have both bottom and top anchor set, to resize in every direction it has to have all 4 anchors set.

Comment: Also you are right we talked about different issues (sorry!). If you set your anchors properly and your controls do not resize that is invalid behavior and I never ever experienced it :/

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the designer of the custom control: [link](http://s14.directupload.net/file/d/3286/r9jqabo4_png.htm), and here is one of the designer which uses the custom control. I rrsized the control, but the used picturebox doesn't resize too... [link](http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3286/97z8p62b_png.htm)

Comment: Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Sorry, was AFK for whole weekend. What happens when you resize your user control to remove that offset?

Comment: It reacts like there weren't any anchors set... I can do what I want, but when I resize the outer form, the inner elements ob the control don't resize, too. It's silly..